# Sync MySql Replication from Master2 to Master1 after failover

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, master-master-replication

Due to Disk space issue Master2 server crashed and it was rebuilt again using mysqldump of Master1.
Both Master 1 and Master2 are in sync and Master2 is in Read_only mode.
During the crash, I stopped the Slave instance in Master1 and it's been over a week now. Now how to restart replication from Master2 to Master1.
Can changing the Master Log position in Master1 to current Master2 status works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Master2 is in read-only;

Master2: `SHOW MASTER STATUS`

Master1:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST = 'host_name'
MASTER_USER = 'user_name'
MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password'
MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'master_log_name'
MASTER_LOG_POS = master_log_pos;

START SLAVE;
```

Where the master log file name/pos are from the Master2 `SHOW MASTER STATUS`

The rapidly changing master status isn't an issue as its binary logs are from Master1 anyway. Master1 won't write its own binary log message back again when received via replication.